# Solaris find command

Tags: find, solaris

In Solaris, what is the syntax of `find` command to find files having multiple file name formats?

Eg: In my current directory and in its sub-directories if I have files like `test.log`, `sample.out`, `demo.buf` and some other files, how can I write single `find` command to find these 3 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the correct one

```
find . \( -name "test.log" -o -name "sample.out" -o -name "demo.buf" \) -print
```

Comment: How to use "find" command for regular expressions like the following in Solaris:
`find / -type f \( -perm +111 -regex ".*[0-9]$" -o -regex ".*[mh]$" \) -exec ls -lT {} \;`

I need to find files and add multiple regex formats to like about to be found at the same time in Solaris. I have managed to do it in Mac OSX and Linux, but it seems that Solaris doesn't support -regex flag.

Answer (score 1):

Same as all other Unixes:

```
 find . -name test.log -o -name sample.out -o name demo.buf
```

Comment: Vanya - No they don't. If they don't contain special characters--spaces, wildcards, etc.--they don't need to be quoted.